# How to identify an ID with values in at least one column for all rows?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with the cloumns: id, name, year, rop, des, cax, pcld.

I need to identify the **id**  with the value **"1"** in at least one column (**rop**, **des**, **cax** e **pcld**) for all years (2014, 2015, 2016, 2017). After that, I need to identify those that have been discontinued over the years (Ex: 2014 = 1, 2015 = 1, 2016 = 0).

So, as a first step, I thought about transposing the data.frame,  to look like this:

```
 id | name | conta | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017
 
 3243 | teste| rop   |   1  |   0  |  0    | 1
 3243 | teste| des   |   0  |   1  |  0    | 0
 3243 | teste| cax   |   0  |   0  |  1    | 0
 3243 | teste| pcld  |   0  |   0  |  0    | 0
```

In the next step, id "3243" would be identified. It has at least one value "1" in all years (columns).

I have been trying to transpose:

```
library(magrittr)

dados   %>% dplyr::select(id, name, year, rop, des, cax, pcld) %>% 
            tidyr::pivot_longer(
                                 cols = -c('id', 'name'),
                                 names_to = 'Conta'

                                )
```

Data:

```
structure(list(
    id = c(1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 22222,22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333,3243,3243,3243,3243), 
    name = c("empresa", "empresa", "empresa", "empresa","firma", "firma", "firma", "firma", "loja", "loja","teste","teste","teste","teste"), 
    year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2014,2015,2014, 2015, 2016, 2017),
    rop = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
    des = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    cax = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
    pcld = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
    row.names = c(NA,14L), class = "data.frame")
```

There is a better way to do it?

Comment: Your example dput doesn't have 3243

Comment: Do you need `names(which(sapply(split(dados[4:7], dados$id, drop = TRUE), function(x) all(rowSums(x) > 0))))`

Comment: @akun, just added 3243 to my dput.

Comment: Based on the new data, I get `[1] "3243"  "3333"  "22222" "33333"` to satisfy the condition.  May be you had a typo i.e. `2222` instead of `22222` and `3333` instead of `33333`

Comment: @akun, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we want to subset the 'id' where at least one of the column from 'rop' to 'pcld' have 1 in its column for all rows, then do a group by 'id' and `filter` by creating a logical vector with `rowSums`, and wrap with `all`

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(all(rowSums(select(cur_data(), rop:pcld)) > 0)) %>%
   ungroup
```

---

Or another option is `if_any` (`dplyr` version `1.0.4`) with `all`

```
dados %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(all(if_any(rop:pcld, as.logical)))
```

i.e. `if_any` loops over the columns `rop` to `pcld`, convert the binary to logical (`as.logical`), returns TRUE/FALSE as a vector if any of the columns for a row have 1, then wrap the logical vector with `all` so that it returns a single TRUE (when all rows have at least one 1 for any column) or FALSE (when any row doesn't have a 1 for all the columns) to subset the 'id'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 df %>% group_by(id,year) %>% 
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(C=max(rop,des,cax,pcld)) %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(sum(C)==4) %>% 
        select(-C) %>%
        ungroup
```